# org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 Generated Serializable Classes

Tags: maven, jaxb

I am using org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2. I have a set of XSDs that I like the generated classes implements java.io.Serializable.

How should I configure my pom.xml

Regards,

Nami

Comment: I solved it by using binding.xjb

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing (Generate classes that are serializeable using mvn plugin).  Could you elaborate? How did you use a file "binding.xjb" to do this.